# Image swap with progress bar increase/decrease onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create image swap with the progress bar increase/decrease when the button clicked. This first problem is working but the second one is not working. On the second one, image won't swap after the fist button ("mark completed") clicked.

```js
$(document).ready(function($){
    var progress = 20;
    var picSource = document.getElementById("mark-complete").src; 
var notcomplete = "https://www.w3schools.com/images/picture.jpg";
var completed = "https://www.w3schools.com/images/lamp.jpg";      


function changePic() {
  if (picSource == notcomplete) {
    picSource = completed;
  } else {
    picSource = notcomplete;
  }
}
document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function() {
  changePic();
  document.getElementById("mark-complete").src = picSource; 
}
document.getElementById("btn2").onclick = function() {
  changePic();
  document.getElementById("mark-complete2").src = picSource; 
}


    $("#pg1 input").on('change', function(){
        if ($("#pg1 input").is(":checked") === true) {
        progress = progress+5;
        $('#blips > .xp-progress').attr("style","width:" + progress + "%");
        }
        else if ($("#pg1 input").is(":checked") === false) {
        progress = progress-5;
        $('#blips > .xp-progress').attr("style","width:" + progress + "%");
        }
    });
 
   $("#pg2 input").on('change', function(){
        if ($("#pg2 input").is(":checked") === true) {
        progress = progress+5;
        $('#blips > .xp-progress').attr("style","width:" + progress + "%");
        }
        else if ($("#pg2 input").is(":checked") === false) {
        progress = progress-5;
        $('#blips > .xp-progress').attr("style","width:" + progress + "%");
        }
    });

});
```

```css
.xp-progress { background-color: darkred;
    height: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="blips" class="xp-line">
          <div class="xp-progress" role="progressbar" style="width:20%">
            <span class="sr-only" style="color:blue;"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        

<img id="mark-complete" src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/picture.jpg" style="width:80px; float: right;">
<hr>
<p></p>
<label id="pg1" style="cursor:pointer;border:2px solid grey; padding: 5px 10px; border-radius: 4px;">Mark Completed!
  <input type="checkbox" id="btn"  style="display:none;">
</label>


<hr>
<p></p>                    
<img id="mark-complete2" src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/picture.jpg" style="width:80px; float: right;">

<label id="pg2" style="cursor:pointer;border:2px solid grey; padding: 5px 10px; border-radius: 4px;">Mark Completed!2
  <input type="checkbox" id="btn2"  style="display:none;">
</label>
```

I know it has to do with "getelementbyid" but What did i do wrong?
Here is the demo: https://plnkr.co/UGWOqpdeCDhXuS9MMXfI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

picSource is always equals to path to your first image (document.getElementById("mark-complete").src).
You need to pass your current image to changePic and compare it on click event. Updated changePic returns needed src for image.

```js
$(document).ready(function($){
  var progress = 20;    
  var notcomplete = "https://www.w3schools.com/images/picture.jpg";
  var completed = "https://www.w3schools.com/images/lamp.jpg";      

  function changePic(source) {
    if (source == notcomplete) {
      return completed;
    } else {
      return notcomplete;
    }
  }
document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function() {  
  var imgSrc=document.getElementById("mark-complete").src;
  document.getElementById("mark-complete").src = changePic(imgSrc); 
}
document.getElementById("btn2").onclick = function() {
  var imgSrc=document.getElementById("mark-complete2").src;
  document.getElementById("mark-complete2").src = changePic(imgSrc); 
}


    $("#pg1 input").on('change', function(){
        if ($("#pg1 input").is(":checked") === true) {
        progress = progress+5;
        $('#blips > .xp-progress').attr("style","width:" + progress + "%");
        }
        else if ($("#pg1 input").is(":checked") === false) {
        progress = progress-5;
        $('#blips > .xp-progress').attr("style","width:" + progress + "%");
        }
    });
 
   $("#pg2 input").on('change', function(){
        if ($("#pg2 input").is(":checked") === true) {
        progress = progress+5;
        $('#blips > .xp-progress').attr("style","width:" + progress + "%");
        }
        else if ($("#pg2 input").is(":checked") === false) {
        progress = progress-5;
        $('#blips > .xp-progress').attr("style","width:" + progress + "%");
        }
    });

});
```

```css
.xp-progress { background-color: darkred;
    height: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="blips" class="xp-line">
          <div class="xp-progress" role="progressbar" style="width:20%">
            <span class="sr-only" style="color:blue;"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        

<img id="mark-complete" src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/picture.jpg" style="width:80px; float: right;">
<hr>
<p></p>
<label id="pg1" style="cursor:pointer;border:2px solid grey; padding: 5px 10px; border-radius: 4px;">Mark Completed!
  <input type="checkbox" id="btn"  style="display:none;">
</label>


<hr>
<p></p>                    
<img id="mark-complete2" src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/picture.jpg" style="width:80px; float: right;">

<label id="pg2" style="cursor:pointer;border:2px solid grey; padding: 5px 10px; border-radius: 4px;">Mark Completed!2
  <input type="checkbox" id="btn2"  style="display:none;">
</label>
```

Comment: Thank you! that makes sense now

Comment: @EhkaluMoo don't forget to mark answer as right to close the question.

Comment: I tried but can't because I don't have enough reputation

Comment: @EhkaluMoo To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `picSource` remains set to the `src` of the last image that was changed.

You've made this way more complicated then it has to be, here is a simplified version:

```js
$(function() {
  var progress = 20;
  var notcomplete = "https://www.w3schools.com/images/picture.jpg";
  var completed = "https://www.w3schools.com/images/lamp.jpg";

  $("#btn, #btn2").click(function() {
    // Get a reference to the appropriate image based on the id of the pushed button.
    var $img = this.id === 'btn' ? $("#mark-complete") : $("#mark-complete2");
    // Toggle the image.
    if ($img.attr("src") === notcomplete) {
      $img.attr("src", completed);
    } else {
      $img.attr("src", notcomplete);
    }
  });


  $("#pg1 input, #pg2 input").on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      progress = progress + 5;
    } else {
      progress = progress - 5;
    }
    $('#blips > .xp-progress').css("width", progress + "%");
  });
});
```

```css
.xp-progress {
  background-color: darkred;
  height: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="blips" class="xp-line">
  <div class="xp-progress" role="progressbar" style="width:20%">
    <span class="sr-only" style="color:blue;"></span>
  </div>
</div>


<img id="mark-complete" src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/picture.jpg" style="width:80px; float: right;">
<hr>
<p></p>
<label id="pg1" style="cursor:pointer;border:2px solid grey; padding: 5px 10px; border-radius: 4px;">Mark Completed!
  <input type="checkbox" id="btn"  style="display:none;">
</label>


<hr>
<p></p>
<img id="mark-complete2" src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/picture.jpg" style="width:80px; float: right;">

<label id="pg2" style="cursor:pointer;border:2px solid grey; padding: 5px 10px; border-radius: 4px;">Mark Completed!2
  <input type="checkbox" id="btn2"  style="display:none;">
</label>
```